# url.format is not a function at ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

I've upgraded my React project to Webpack 5, upgraded react-dev-utils to the latest version as well

Webpack Dev Server is giving me this error:

```
main.js:3940 Uncaught TypeError: url.format is not a function
    at ./node_modules/react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient.js (react-dev-utils.js:193:36)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you already provided a polyfill for native node library in webpack 5 config?